# JSON Gem fails to build on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, rubygems, cygwin

Okay, got a pretty basic Ruby 1.9.3 install with DevKit on Windows XP.

When I try to do a `rails new myapp`, it gets to installing json and dies.

```
Installing json (1.7.5) with native extensions C:\devkit\bin\make.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 6

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
      0 [main] us 0 init_cheap: VirtualAlloc pointer is null, Win32 error 487
AllocationBase 0x0, BaseAddress 0x60E90000, RegionSize 0x170000, State 0x10000
C:\devkit\bin\make.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 6


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing json (1.7.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.7.5'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I tried installing manually and a couple versions older, but no dice. Also updated my devkit to the latest version from RubyInstaller.org in case that was the issue, but no luck there either

Comment: The error "[Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap](https://www.google.com/search?q=Couldn't+reserve+space+for+cygwin's+heap)" is the key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this page: http://support.code-red-tech.com/CodeRedWiki/VirtualAllocPointerNull which said that the version of msys.dll in some installations won't work, but replacing with the attached file sorted me out.